# No throttle Response at low RPM, Normal performance at normal high RPM

Tags: stall, maf, lean, hilux

I own a 2007 Hilux, 1kd-ftv 3.0 diesel.

Recently my car was occasionally stalling or trying to stall at idle, and having complete engine hesitation from time to time, where the engine would rev when pushing down throttle but no drive and then suddenly it would kick in (complete hesitation, not turbo lag).

My car threw check engine light  codes:

- P0102: MAF or VAF A Circuit Low Input
- P0113: IAT Sensor 1 Circuit High Input

All problems pointed to a dirty or failing MAF sensor, I bought some proper mass air flow sensor cleaner cleaned the sensor and the engine codes went away and the car was driving so much better, no longer running lean.

Over the last 4 days its been driving perfectly with no problems, prior to the clean it was having problems at least once a trip (20 min drive). Unfortunately though this morning it had another problem that I hadn't seen before. The car was having no performance at low RPM in a higher gear, absolutely none or little power to the driveline with the engine reving, as soon as you went down a gear into a higher RPM it would be completely fine, but as soon as it was in RPMs it would have no power (completely different to just low power at low rpm, this was almost like limp mode).

Anyone possibly know what it could be ? Im gonna give the sensor another clean but maybe I need a new one all together.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!